# With Capybara and Rspec, how to disable config :all for a specific test

Tags: rspec, capybara, automated-tests

I have not so few tests so in order to save time I skip the login process with the following config:

```
config.before :all, type: :feature do
    stub_login
    visit "/auth=admin:123456&origin=http://#{Capybara.current_session.server.host}:#{Capybara.current_session.server.port}"
end
```

But now that I have to test the login screen I'm in a pickle: Any attempt to go to the login screen (visit or log out) will result in a logged in page as the stub return the relevant data for log in state.

I wonder how can I cancel this specific config? Is there a way to flag it so a specific test (or spec) could ignore it?

Thoughts & hints? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I split the "config.before :all":

```
config.before :all, type: :logged do
    stub_login
end

config.before :all, type: :feature do
    visit '.......'
end
```

and the tests from:

```
describe 'some tests with login', type: [:feature, :logged] do
.....
```

to:

```
describe 'login screen tests', type: :feature do
.....
```

another, better solution, would be:

```
config.before :all do |spec|

    not_logged = spec.class.metadata[:not_logged]
    if not_logged
        ......not logged script
    else
       ......logged script 
    end
```

and the spec:

```
describe 'login view', type: :feature, :not_logged=> true do
    .....
end
```